# Configure program that uses gtk1.2

Tags: linux, makefile, gtk, shared-libraries

I am trying to build a program as most others available on linux:
configure, make, make install.

However when I try to configure it I get the following message:

```
checking for gtk-config... no
checking for GTK - version >= 1.2.0... no
*** The gtk-config script installed by GTK could not be found
*** If GTK was installed in PREFIX, make sure PREFIX/bin is in
*** your path, or set the GTK_CONFIG environment variable to the
*** full path to gtk-config.
configure: error: Cannot find GTK: Is gtk-config in path?
```

I have got gtk 2.x on the host machine. And when I run `which` and `locate` on gtk-config I get nothing back. Since I have the source what patches can I apply to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the development files for GTK 1.2; the name of the package depends on your distribution.

I'd like to warn you, though, that GTK 1.2 was last released 15 years ago, in 2001, and hasn't been updated since — which also implies that the application you're trying to build is also hopelessly outdated.

GTK+ 2.0.0 was also released in 2001 and it's currently in deep maintenance mode (the latest version is 2.24.29 and was released in 2015); GTK+ 3.0.0 was released in 2011, and it's the currently developed version of the API.

You cannot really apply patches to compile an application written with the GTK 1.x API using any newer *major* versions of GTK+ (e.g. 2.x or 3.x); each time the major version of GTK is bumped, the API is changed in a non-compatible way. You would need to port the application to the new API.

Additionally, if an application depends on GTK 1.x it's also likely that it will depend on older versions of existing libraries; or deprecated ones. You will need to find all the dependencies and ensure that they can be installed in parallel with the ones you have installed in your system.

Comment: I use Ubuntu and I think all repos are cleared of gtk1.x. I downloaded gtk1.2.10 and am trying to build that from source. but even that is giving me problems

Comment: gtk 1.x is depecrated, and buggy. You should use upgrade at least with the lastest gtk 2 bundle. If you are trying to build gtk 1.2 you maybe need outdated libraries that even modern desktop enviroments or distros don't give support.

Comment: I believe I found the easiest workaround for this: Have a Virtual machine run an old linux distro.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the compatibility wrappers developed by OpenSUSE team that try to emulate GTK1.2 by some wrappers and/or automatically patching source code to be compiled, to be able to use GTK2.0 instead.

Have a look at https://github.com/openSUSE/gtk1-compat - perhaps it may work for you. I didn't test it, however, myself.